Understanding Issue with lmfit() function in code for Gene expression
I was setting up a design matrix for a dataset to understand gene expression for osteoarthritis and when using the lmfit() function, it stated that the expression matrix has zero rows and I am unsure how to potentially fix this issue. The dataset that I am using is GSE117999 from the Gene Expression Omnibus.
This is the code I used:
#   Differential expression analysis with limma
library(GEOquery)
library(limma)
library(umap)

# load series and platform data from GEO

gset <- getGEO("GSE117999", GSEMatrix =TRUE, AnnotGPL=FALSE)
if (length(gset) > 1) idx <- grep("GPL20844", attr(gset, "names")) else idx <- 1
gset <- gset[[idx]]

# make proper column names to match toptable 
fvarLabels(gset) <- make.names(fvarLabels(gset))

# group membership for all samples
gsms <- "111111111111000000000000"
sml <- strsplit(gsms, split="")[[1]]

# log2 transformation
ex <- exprs(gset)
qx <- as.numeric(quantile(ex, c(0., 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.99, 1.0), na.rm=T))
LogC <- (qx[5] > 100) ||
  (qx[6]-qx[1] > 50 && qx[2] > 0)
if (LogC) { ex[which(ex <= 0)] <- NaN
exprs(gset) <- log2(ex) }

# assign samples to groups and set up design matrix
gs <- factor(sml)
groups <- make.names(c("Experiment","Control"))
levels(gs) <- groups
gset$group <- gs
design <- model.matrix(~group + 0, gset)
colnames(design) <- levels(gs)

gset <- gset[complete.cases(exprs(gset)), ] # skip missing values

fit <- lmFit(gset, design)  # fit linear model

I expected an assignment of values to an array for further analysis of data, after looking again at the variables that I had found, I couldn't find anything that I could improve on. Sorry if this seems vague, I'm new to R and am trying to learn this.
